# How to use jquery ui button with knockout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have the following html:

```
<button id="simpleBtn" data-bind="jqButton: true, click: runTest, style: {backgroundColor: color}">Click me</button>
```

and the following model:

```
function Test(testName, test) {
            var vm = {};

            vm.result = ko.observable(false);
            vm.testName = testName;
            vm.color = ko.computed(function (){
                return vm.result() === true ? 'green' : 'red';
            }, vm);

            vm.test = test;
            vm.runTest = function () {
                var result = vm.test();
                vm.result(result);
            }

            return vm;
        }

        ko.bindingHandlers.jqButton = {
            init: function (element) {
                $(element).button();
            }
        }

        ko.applyBindings(Test('Name', function () {
            //test code
        }));
```

I want to change the style of button, but this code doesn't work. What should I do to make it work?

Comment: What are you trying to do? I'm having a hard time deciphering this. Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: @MarkB yes, please: http://jsfiddle.net/Xjt4f/. 
I want to change color of button 'Run test' on green or red depending on the result of test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using the css binding instead? [Here's an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/barryman9000/w5Ur8/1/)

```
<td><button id="testBtn" data-bind="jqButton: {enable: true}, click: runTest, css: StyleRunTest">Run test</button></td>

function applyKnockoutModel() {
    function Test(testName, test) {
        var vm = {};
        vm.StyleRunTest = ko.observable('btn-valid');
        vm.result = ko.observable(false);
        vm.testName = testName;
        vm.color = ko.computed(function () {
                return vm.result() === true ? vm.StyleRunTest('btn-valid') : vm.StyleRunTest('btn-invalid');
            };
        };
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It must be an issue with the order of loading scripts. Check your console for errors. Your code works here jsfiddle.net/zA7L3/

Comment: oh, you just need to use background instead of backgroundColor in order to replace the background image for the button.

Comment: I'm afraid I do not quite understand you. Сan you write how it will be work?

Comment: instead of "style: {backgroundColor: color}" do "style: {background: color}"